# C++ Meyer's Singleton with arguments

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

Is it possible to define a Meyer's singleton (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289)) with arguments?

I know it is possible with the GOF style singleton (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395459/how-to-pass-argument-in-a-singleton)),

but I can't seem to make it work with Meyer's singletons:

```
// ...
public:

    static S& getInstance()
    {
        static S instance; // no way to pass arguments here ...
        return instance;
    }
```

**EDIT**:

I want a single `Init` function, and multiple `getInstance`.
So a typical usage is something like:

```
S::Init(5, 6.4);
foo(S::getInstance());
bar(S::getInstance());
```

Comment: Exactly the same as in your linked answer. You give the initializer after `static S instance` as in `static S instance(...);` or `static S instance{...};` Could you clarify where the problem is?

Comment: I want to have an init call: `S::Init(8,7.25)` then use with `S::getInstance()` ... and guard each method with its assert: `Init` will be guarded with `instance == nullptr` and `getInstance` will be guarded with `instance != nullptr` ...

Comment: You should just follow the single responsibility principle and move out lazy initialization code from instance fetching function.

Comment: @user7860670 could you please explain?

Comment: Put your other requirements in the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: My point is that `Singleton` should have only `Get_Instance` and `Set_Instance` functions and should not be performing any kind of initialization at all. That is `Singleton` should have only a single responsibility - providing access to a single instance of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just store the initialization parameters in statics. Example:

```
class S {
public:
    static void Init(int i)
    {
        i_ = i;
        initialized_ = true;
    }

    static S& getInstance()
    {
        if (!initialized_) {
            throw SomeException;
        }
        static S instance(i_);
        return instance;
    }

private:
    S(int) { }

    static int i_;
    static bool initialized_;
};
```

Remember to actually define the statics in the implementation (`.cpp`) file:

```
int S::i_ = 0;
bool S::initialized_ = false;
```

Obviously you could use Meyer singletons as well for these, but since they're built-in types and do not depend on other data, you wouldn't really gain much.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
  static std::unique_ptr<Singleton>& getObject()
  {
    static std::unique_ptr<Singleton> instance;
    return instance;
  }

  Singleton(int foo);

public:
  static void Init(int foo)
  {
    auto& instance = getObject();
    if (instance) throw std::runtime_error("aleady inited");
    instance.reset(new Singleton(foo));
  }

  static Singleton& getInstance()
  {
    auto& instance = getObject();
    if (!instance) throw std::runtime_error("not inited");    
    return *instance;
  }
};
```

Note that this isn't thread safe and will have undefined behaviour if multiple threads call `Init` or a thread calls `getInstance` whilst another is calling `Init`.

If your parameters could be replaced by template arguments then you could do it this way instead:

```
template <int foo>
class SingletonImpl
{
private:
  SingletonImpl(int f);

public:
  static SingletonImpl<foo>& getInstance()
  {
    static SingletonImpl<foo> instance(foo);
    return instance;
  }
};

using Singleton = SingletonImpl<10>;
```

The best solution is probably to separate initialisation and construction:

```
class Singleton
{
private:
  std::atomic<bool> initialised;
  Singleton()
  : initialised(false)
  {
  }

  Singleton& instanceImpl()
  {
    static Singleton singleton;
    return singleton;
  }

public:
  void Init(int foo)
  {
    auto& instance = instanceImpl();
    if (instance.initialised) throw std::runtime_error("already inited");
    instance.initialised = true;
  }

  Singleton& getInstance()
  {
    auto& instance = instanceImpl();
    if (!instance.initialised) throw std::runtime_error("not inited");
    return instance;
  }
};
```